# Does there exist an analytic function such that $|f(z)|=x$ for $z=x+iy \in D$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Does there exist an analytic function $f=u+iv$ in $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$ such that $|f(z)|=x$ for $z=x+iy \in D$? Prove your response.

I am pretty stuck on this.

I know that $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ and

$$u_x=v_y \quad u_y=-v_x$$

Further, I want to know if it's possible for $u^2(z)+v^2(z)=x^2$ and that's about the place I stick.

## Attempt

We are looking for a function of the $form f(z)=u(z)+v(z)$ such that

$$u^2+v^2=x^2$$

Differentiating with respect to $y$ we have

$$2uu_x+2vv_x=0$$

and so

$$uu_y=-vv_y$$

Supposing $f$ is analytic from the Cauchy-Riemann Equations we have

$$uv_x=vu_x$$

and so

$$uv_x-vu_x=0=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( \frac{u}{v}\right)$$

```
 What about $v^2$? Do we presume it is equal to $1$
```

Integrating gives

$$\frac{u}{v}=c \Rightarrow u=cv$$

where $c$ is some constant. We have

$$u^2+c^2u^2=x^2$$

or 
$$u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+c^2}}$$??

which says $v=\frac{cx}{\sqrt{1+c^2}}$ and since $v^2=1$ we have to have $c^2x^2=1+c^2$ or $x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{c^2}+1}$ which gives us $x$ constant which a contradiction of our assumption $z \in \{z:|z|<1\}$ and so this is not possible.

Comment: $-1/2 \in D$ and you would have $|f(-1/2)| = -1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f$, restricted to the imaginary axis. However, if you mean $|f(z)| = |x|$ and only want to work with the Cauchy-Riemann differential equations (CRDE), derive $u^2 + v^2 = x^2$ with respect to $y$ and use CRDE to see that $u = cv$ for some $c$.

Comment: Or consider the left-hand half of $D$.

Comment: Could you expand a little bit?

Comment: If you have problems, tell me what they are.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are able to conclude that u=cv?

Comment: Have you derived $u^2+v^2 = x^2$ with respect to $y$? What's your result?

Comment: I end up with $u_y u(x,y) = -v_y v(x,y)$

Comment: Now, use CRDE and try to apply the quotient rule (backwards).

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't follow your meaning there.

Comment: I f you don't read carefully, I cannot help you. I wrote in my answer what I mean by CRDE.

Comment: I know what the CRDE are. After applying we get $-v_x \cdot u = u_x v$. I don't know what you mean by quotient rule (backwards)

Comment: There is a minus sign too much. Don't you know the quotient rule? $(f/g)' = (f'g - fg')/g^2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36625/discussion-between-az89-and-friedrich-philipp).

Comment: No. I am going to sleep. 

Comment: You cannot assume v = 1, but you can prove that $v\neq 0$ for $x\neq 0$. In the end, plug in v = cu in the CRDE to see that $c=\pm i$, which is a contradiction as u and v are real-valued.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you mean the equality holds in the open right half disc $D_+.$ Clearly $f$ is not constant. By the open mapping theorem, $f(D_+)$ is open, so it contains an open disc $V$ that does not intersect $(-\infty,0].$ Hence the principal value $\log$ is analytic on $V.$ Thus $\log f(z)$ is analytic on $U=f^{-1}(V).$ This implies $\text { Re }\log f(x+iy) = \ln |f(x+iy)|$ is harmonic on $U.$ But $\ln |f(x+iy)| = \ln x$ in $U$ and the Laplacian of $\ln x$ is never $0$, contradiction.

Comment: I am pretty sure the OP cannot use such "advanced methods".